# built-in function diff() available for vector in MathNet?

Tags: c#, .net, math.net

I'm new to `MathNet` and implementing a code in `C#.Net`.

There is a vector:

```
var X = new DenseVector(new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150 });
```

I need to find  `Y = **diff(X)**` calculating differences between adjacent elements of `X` like:

```
Y = [X(2)-X(1) X(3)-X(2) ... X(m)-X(m-1)]
```

Is there built-in function **diff()** available in `MathNet`? I searched on [MathNet.Numerics/Differentiate](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Differentiation/FiniteDifferenceCoefficients.htm), but its not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use advantages of `MathNet` to make it more expressive.

```
static class VectorExtension
{
    public static Vector<double> Differentiate(this Vector<double> vector)
    {
        var high = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfEnumerable(vector.Skip(1));
        var low = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfEnumerable(vector.Take(vector.Count - 1));
        return  high - low;
    }
}
```

Then

```
var X = new DenseVector(new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 });
Console.WriteLine(X.Differentiate());
```

Gives

```
DenseVector 6-Double
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. It does not appear to be available. But here is a simple function to achieve that.

```
public MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseVector 
Diff(MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseVector X)
{
    var R = new MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseVector(X.Count - 2);
    for (var i = 0; i <= X.Count - 2; i++)
        R(i) = X(i + 1) - X(i);
    return R;
}
```